# Sum of power series with inverse coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients, power-series

Are there any relations between the sums of $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{a_n}$?

For example, I know
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}x^n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}},$$
but how to show that
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{\binom{2n}{n}}=\frac{4\left(\sqrt{4-x}+\sqrt{x}\arcsin{(\frac{\sqrt{x}}2})\right)}{\sqrt{4-x}(4-x)}?$$
(I get the above result from WolframAlpha.)

Comment: Why should there be any relations between them? Also, one might ask the more general question of what is the relation between $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n^\alpha x^n$?

Comment: Try to do this with the power series of $e^x$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, by taking the [Cauchy product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) of the two series, we notice 
$$
\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n\right)
\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{a_n}\right)=
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^n \frac{a_n}{a_{n-j}}x^n
$$

In the case of your particular series, that expression simplifies.  In general, this might not be anything nice looking.